# java properties/xml como constante

Tags: java, xml, annotation, constantes, archivo-de-propiedades

Trato de recoger valores de un archivo `.properties` para usarlo en una anotación, pero no es posible hacerlo con `ResourceBundle` ya que las anotaciones trabajan con constantes y el resultado de este, no lo es.

Probé a cambiar el properties a `.xml` recogiendo los valores con `.getProperty()` y pasa lo mismo.

¿Hay alguna forma de recoger estos valores como constantes? ¿O escribir en el xml como constantes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No<sup>1</sup>.

Las anotaciones son parte del código de la clase. Los parámetros se definen *en tiempo de compilación*, no en tiempo de ejecución. Los métodos de reflection no permiten ningún cambio en las anotaciones.

La opción que tienes para seleccionar una clase con una anotación con un parámetro determinado en tiempo de ejecución es definir una interface, implementar X clases con los X parámetros, y usar un método/clase Factory que se encargue de instanciar la subclase correcta en función de la configuración.

Si quieres más flexibilidad, ya estamos hablando de incorporar inyección de dependencias (por ejemplo, con CDI o Spring) para inyectar clases con las anotaciones específicas según se necesites.

Pero todo esto huele a que estás intentando usar anotaciones para solucionar un problema para el que no están diseñadas; te sugiero que repienses lo que quieres hacer.

---

<sup>1</sup> Quizás haya alguna forma generando clases "on the fly" con javassist y similares. Pero no quiero ir allí, y dudo de que tú quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), sí que hay una forma, y se le conoce como [spel](/questions/tagged/spel).
Mayormente se utiliza en conjunto con la anotación `@Value` de Spring para inyectar el valor, aunque es bueno notar que el campo al que le inyectes el valor no debe ser constante (static final).

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

y en tu properties

```
userBucket.path=${HOME}/bucket
```

Esta técnica se usa mucho en [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) para tener la [configuración de manera externa al código](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

Fuente (en gringo): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot

Adicionalmente igual te interese cargar todo un properties en tu contexto mediante la anotación `@PropertySources`, para ello revisa el artículo [Multiples properties en wildfly](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/multiples-properties-en-wildfly)

Answer (score 0):

utiliza spring, la anotación desde tu archivo java o implementación debería ser así:

```
    @Value("${nombreVariable}"). //como lo tienes en el archivo.properties
    private String nombre; //nombre dentro de tu implementación;
```

tu clase o implementación dale la anotación de `@Component`

en tu archivo `.properties`
`nombreVariable=valor`