# Multiples properties en wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, archivo-de-propiedades

Estoy tratando de desplegar dos [war](/questions/tagged/war) en wildfly y cada uno con un archivo de *properties* diferentes, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar ya que en en el sistema de configuraciones de wildfly solo me deja crear un `spring.config.location`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien podria darme una idea de como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Logre solucionar mi problema y si a alguien tiene el mismo problema la solucion es el siguiente.

en el MyProgramApplication agregar los siguiente:

```html
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:application-dev.properties") } )
public class RestfullExampleApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(RestfullExampleApplication.class, args);
 }
 
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate();
 }

}
```

y en el System Properties agregar lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

separe por coma (,) los archivos .properties que tenga lugar para sus aplicaciones.

espero sea de ayuda a otros

Comment: Te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.